# How to enable insert batching in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

having spring-boot for parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, and facing issues with configuration. I have to create code for somewhat write-heavy application, but JPA insist on issuing inserts one after another. After reading many questions I know, I should configure it somehow like this:

```
#hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
#hibernate.order_inserts=true
#hibernate.order_updates=true
#hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
#spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

but no configuration seems to be the winning one, settings seems simply ignored. Entity PK is UUID generated in a constructor, so there shouldn't be any reason for batching to be unavailable.

How do I know if they are actually ignored? Well, I actually don't know. Using configuration:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

shows individual inserts only, but that's OK, allegedly it always shows this. But if one enables trace logging, allegedly there should be some log from `batcher`, explaining, how he batched the statements. Well, this is not present. Logging on postgres level does not show any batching, but others explained, that allegedly it never shows that. And the effort to configure p6spy on springboot was futile.

Questions:
How can one configure insert batching in springboot? Sorry for asking maybe „duplicately”, but none of >5 answers seemed to be working.

How can we effectively prove, that batching was used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set batch size explicitly for a certain session to perform your task via `session.setJdbcBatchSize(size)`
Here is some test example that works fine with MySql 5.6, Hibernate 5.3 and Spring Boot 2.0.2 irrespective to the global settings like

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10 
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

Test code:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

    @Commit
    @Test
    public void batchInsertTest() {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.setJdbcBatchSize(10);
        for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Batch batch = new Batch();
            batch.setId(i);
            batch.setName("batch"+i);
            session.save(batch);
            if (i%10==0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

In order to see that the batch processing has been in place, we need to turn on statistics, here are settings in SpringBoot's application.property:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

It will generate output after commit like this:

```
Session Metrics {
    34700 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    39725440 nanoseconds spent preparing 11 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    58840328 nanoseconds spent executing 11 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    203702688 nanoseconds spent executing 11 flushes (flushing a total of 100 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

As you can see 11 batches have been prepared.

Very simple time processing measurement (based on System.nanoTime()) gives the following picture when inserting: 50000 entries with and without batch of size=1000

- Batch of 1000: 10.5-10.3 sec
- No batch: 18.5-19.3 sec.

On my very old Intel CPU, Quad Core 9550